# Get an image of a vbhtml view as a byte array and save it to an oracle database

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help on an mvc application in vb.net. In general terms I need to receive an image through the view and get it to work on the controller. I need to do this to convert the image to a byte array and save it to an oracle database. So my idea is to get the image and in the controller to convert it to a byte array or maybe there is some way to get the image already as a byte array and pass that array to the controller to save it to the database.

something like this its my View :

```
<div class="span11">    
            <div class="span4" id="depnac">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.DepNacPER)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.DepNacPER, Model.DepNacPER, New With {.class = "form-control"})
        </div>
```

and this is my Model :

```
<Display(Name:="Region of birth")>
<Required(ErrorMessage:="you must select a option")>
Property DepNacPER As SelectList
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core app right now that uploads images.  The image comes through to the controller via the request as a `Stream`.  I'm then creating an `Image` object from that `Stream` but you could just read the data from it directly.  That said, you might want to try to create an `Image` object to confirm that the data does represent a valid image.

Here's some relevant code from the view's script:

```
function uploadImage()
{
    // This is a file upload control in a hidden div.
    var image = $("#imageFile");

    if (image[0].files.length > 0)
    {
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append(image[0].files[0].name, image[0].files[0]);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("POST", "@Url.Content("~/events/uploadimage")");
        xhr.send(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (response.saveSuccessful)
                {
                    // ...
                } else
                {
                    window.location.replace("@Url.Content("~/error")");
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.onerror = function(err, result)
        {
            alert("Error: " + err.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm in the process of replacing that code with some jQuery that does the heavy lifting but haven't got that far yet.

Here's some relevant code from the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadImage()
    {
        var requestForm = Request.Form;
        StringValues tempImageFileNames;
        string tempImageFileName = null;
        string imageUrl = null;
        var saveSuccessful = true;
        var requestFiles = requestForm.Files;

        if (requestFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            // A file has been uploaded.
            var file = requestFiles[0];

            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var originalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
                    {
                        // Do whatever you like with the Image here.
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    saveSuccessful = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (saveSuccessful)
        {
            return Json(new {saveSuccessful, tempImageFileName, imageUrl});
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new {saveSuccessful});
        }
    }
```

Sorry, it didn't occur to me at first that you're after VB code and this is C#.  Hopefully you can still get the idea and I'll take the hit if someone dislikes the answer.